# Symfony 2 value on Enitty field

Tags: symfony, entity, field

I made a form with Symfony 2, my problem is that the entity fields doesn't show the value from the database, the other fields on the form are compiled well and the data I pass to the form contains the right value.

The code in form type is:

```
->add('nazione', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'CRIPatentiBundle:Nazioni',
                'property' => 'nomeEsteso',
                )
             )
```

the twig code is:

```
{{ form_widget(form.nazione) }}
```

the dump of the array shows the right value in the database

```
-nazione: 102
```

But the select in html shows the first value, not the one is specified and the value property of the select item is 102

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't your class be written like this : `CRIPatentiBundle\Entity\Nazioni` ?

Comment: @GuillaumeFache No, both syntax are correct.

Comment: @xurshid29 my bad then

Comment: @GuillaumeFache Or even you can use `Nazioni::class` if your PHP's v5.6

Comment: Can you provide the code for the controller method that renders the form?